# Understanding the graph of the displacement of a particle wirh respect to time

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

[image: The motion of a particle is plotted in <span class=]$(t,y)$ plane" />

At time $t=0$ the position of the particle is $3 ft$, and at time $t=2$ the position of the particle is $11ft$. At time $t=0$ the velocity of the particle must have been zero. So if its the motion of the particle that has been plotted, then why doesn't it start at the point $(0,3)$? The line also extends backward. What does that mean?

Comment: The time $t=0$ is an arbitrary choice, and the particle can also have been moving at times $t<0$. Why must the particle's velocity have been $0$ at $t=0$?

Comment: So what does mean by $t=0$? I mean when we are driving a car, then we start counting the time elapsed.

Comment: We are free to choose $t=0$ at whatever point in time which is convenient. It has no meaning, just convention. Of course, in many cases a certain choice seems more obvious and natural than other choices, but still, everybody is free to put the point $t=0$ anywhere they like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We might think of the moving particle as an ant crawling...Suppose we we want to study how far an ant moves over the course of a couple minutes, say staring at $10$:$00$, it may very well be that the ant has been crawling since $9:58$, but that we don't start measuring distance or time until $10$:$00$.

In this case, we would put $t = 0$ minutes at $10$:$00$. Then given the fact that the ant started moving $2$ minutes earlier, we might say that at $t = -2$, the ant started moving.

In short, we can think of $t = 0$ as representing a relative starting time, relative to when measurement starts, for example.

Comment: Very well, the best answer!

Comment: You're welcome, Samama!

Comment: @amWhy: Nice feedback again! +1